# [rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot3_description' not found

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the steps from the Robotis e-Manual website
http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/overview/

### Currently:

- I'm running `roscore` on remote pc.
- I'm running `roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch`  on turtlebot pc.

But every time I run the command below on the remote pc:

```
 rosrun rviz rviz -d `rospack find turtlebot3_description`/rviz/model.rviz
```

I get is error:

```
[rospack] Error: package 'turtlebot3_description' not found
[ INFO] [1545426118.806539706]: rviz version 1.13.1
[ INFO] [1545426118.806617414]: compiled against Qt version 5.9.5
[ INFO] [1545426118.806637712]: compiled against OGRE version 1.9.0 (Ghadamon)
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
[ INFO] [1545426119.532401104]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1545426119.533532469]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6).
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

After I get this message,a window with the title `model.rivz* -VZiz` and it's suppose to display the robot and it doesn't. Also I get a global status error.[image: image description]

How do I fix this??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311337/%5Brospack%5D-error:-package-%27turtlebot3_description%27-not-found/) by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2018-12-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found a solution for this. After you have installed ROS, you need to create a ROS workspace and setup a bash.
Immediately you need to make sure your workspace is properly overlayed by the setup script, make sure ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable includes the directory you're in.
Follow this website, step 3 for instruction--  http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

---

Originally posted by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) with karma: 42 on 2018-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0